# Visual Studio create new solution from existing git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, version-control, solution

I need to create a new solution that has the existing git repo as a remote (not cloned) and pulls from that so that I can start working. Previously I tried blank solution and adding to source control, committing and then adding the remote but I received the error "an upstream branch" (master) "already exists". I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013. Sorry if this is unclear in any way, I'll be happy to clarify on any details. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if it sounds rough, but I don't find words to make it less blunt.

You misunderstood. There is no way to work on a code from GIT repo without first "cloning" that repository. Even in CVS or SVN you had "working copy". Even with TFS you have the source files on your disk. Basically, this is what GIT calls "cloning": you must download (clone) the files (repository), and then you can open them in IDE and work on them, and then you can commit and send it back to server.

Exact steps depend on the GIT client and IDE you are using. I use VS but I don;t like it's GIT client, and I use GitExtensions+commandline+Explorer integration for that. However, if you want to use the built-in GIT client, [here's some tutorial on how to clone&open solution](http://www.malgreve.net/2014/06/17/cloning-getting-code-from-git-repository-to-visual-studio/)

Comment: I cloned it manually, I didn't realise that the command line command automatically added the remote, so all I had to do was create a new Visual Studio solution in the cloned repo and add my auth details when I synced

Answer (score 0):

I think standard practice here would be to just clone the repo and start working ASAP.

Comment: I'm able to work with the cloned repo, but I need a long-term fix that lets me commit and sync with the remote repo

Comment: Why can't you commit and pull from this cloned repository?

Comment: I'm setting up a new solution and adding this repository as a remote, do I need to clone it first and then add the remote?

Comment: @LukeMoll: article-tutorial http://www.malgreve.net/2014/06/17/cloning-getting-code-from-git-repository-to-visual-studio/